# Undefined reference when trying to define template <typename T> operator<

Tags: c++, templates, operators, typename

I am trying to implement my own `BigInteger` class with overloaded operators. So I have

```
bool operator<(const BigInteger& left, const BigInteger& right) {
  // some code
}
```

which works OK, and now I try to overload `operator<` also as following:

```
template <typename T>
bool operator<(const BigInteger& left, const T& right) {
  BigInteger big_right(right);
  return (left < big_right);
}
```

But in *main.cpp* following code

```
numeric::types::BigInteger a{17};
std::cout << std::boolalpha;
std::cout << (a < 16) << std::endl;
```

cannot compile, error `undefined reference to 'bool numeric::types::operator< <int>(numeric::types::BigInteger const&, int const&)'`

P.S. `BigInteger` is in `namespace numeric::types {}`

`BigInteger` of course has int constructor:

```
BigInteger::BigInteger(int int_number) {
  // some code
}
```

Is it possible to somehow make this work?

P.P.S. This is not anyhow connected with [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file), because BigInteger is just `class BigInteger`, not a `template <typename T> class BigInteger`

So in code

```
numeric::types::BigInteger a{10};
std::cout << (a < 2) << std::endl;
std::cout << (a < 2LL) << std::endl;
```

both of cout's should work correctly

Comment: Is the `operator<` definition in a .cpp file?

Comment: Definition is in *big_integer.cpp*, declaration is in *big_integer.h*

Comment: Then read the dupe, it answers your question.